# Swift - IOS, Spring : Problem with sending and receiving STOMP messages with StompClientLib and Spring

Tags: ios, swift, spring-websocket, stomp

Stomp client gets connected successfully to socket, when I try to send message to server, server method on given path is not executed at all. I tried with full 'ws://localhost:8080/app/hello' path, but with no success.
When I use JS client on browser, it works perfectly.
My guess is that I'm giving the wrong path for send and subscribe methods.
Here is code from server and client implementation.

Spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements 
       WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
}

}

@Controller
public class GreetingController {


@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public Greeting greeting(String message) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Message sent: " + message);
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message + "!"));
}

}
```

Swift Client:

```
import UIKit
import StompClientLib

class ViewController: UIViewController, StompClientLibDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nameInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var messagesLabel: UILabel!

var socketClient = StompClientLib()

let url = URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket/websocket/")!
let subscribePath = "/topic/greetings"
let sendMessagePath = "/app/hello"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    socketClient.openSocketWithURLRequest(request: NSURLRequest(url: url) , delegate: self)

    socketClient.subscribe(destination: subscribePath)
}

@IBAction func subscribeAction() {
}

@IBAction func disconnectAction() {
}

@IBAction func sendAction() {
    let name = nameInput.text!

    socketClient.sendMessage(message: name, toDestination: sendMessagePath, withHeaders: nil, withReceipt: nil)
}


func stompClient(client: StompClientLib!, didReceiveMessageWithJSONBody jsonBody: AnyObject?, withHeader header: [String : String]?, withDestination destination: String) {
    print(jsonBody)
}

func stompClientJSONBody(client: StompClientLib!, didReceiveMessageWithJSONBody jsonBody: String?, withHeader header: [String : String]?, withDestination destination: String) {
    print(jsonBody)
}

func stompClientDidDisconnect(client: StompClientLib!) {
    print("Socket disconnected")
}

func stompClientDidConnect(client: StompClientLib!) {

}

func serverDidSendReceipt(client: StompClientLib!, withReceiptId receiptId: String) {
    print("serverDidSendReceipt")

}

func serverDidSendError(client: StompClientLib!, withErrorMessage description: String, detailedErrorMessage message: String?) {
    print("serverDidSendError")

}

func serverDidSendPing() {
    print("serverDidSendPing")

}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Did it print anything?

Comment: I posted the solution.
I guess that I called subscribe(destination:) too soon, it should be placed in method after didConnect is called.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was in subscribing too soon.

```
func stompClientDidConnect(client: StompClientLib!) {

    socketClient.subscribe(destination: topic)
}
```

Call to subscribe to topic should be in this function.
If someone else did the same mistake as I, this is the right solution.